# Sql creating tables

Tags: sql

So I'm self-thought programmer until I finish primary  and high school and I came across one assignment I tried but couldn't solve... Assignment goes like this: In base data there are two tables (accounts and payment history) table 1 (accounts):id int username varchar balance numeric (9,2) table 2(payment history):id int user int oldbalance numeric (9,2) newbalance numeric (9,2) time timestamp. It is necessary to create a function that checks whether the user from the table users has a certain amount of funds. For example: select check_funds(1,100) it checks that user 1 has 100 in his account. It is necessary to create a procedure that transfers money from one user's account to another user's account. If the first user does not have enough money in the account, the operation should be suspended. Every money transfer operation should be remembered in the payment history table. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this and sorry for bad english

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Have you thought about paragraphs?